# Servo broken? Explanation, Solution

Tags: motor, servo

I had a question, I tried to control a servo with the arduino, to the servo I attached a stick and at the end of the stick a little weight. After runing my code my servo tried to move the stick, but maybe it had not enough torque to move it so after that I paused the code. Then I tried to control the servo again without weight and this time it didn´t moved. Is it broken? why? Is there a posible solution? Thanks

Comment: There is really no way for us to tell. Its possible that its broken but if all you did was stall it I find that pretty unlikly.

Comment: How are you driving these servo's? Bear in kind that servos are quite different from regular motors... http://handyboard.com/hb/faq/hardware-faqs/dc-vs-servo/

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code you are using, it is difficult to know if you are attempting to drive the servo correctly.

Remember, with a servo, the PWM signal is a positioning signal, not a duty cycle signal as used with speed control on regular dc motors.

Answer (score 0):

You may have broken the gears if the servo was not rated for the load applied or if the servo was rotated too far (by software) 1ms and 2ms should be your (conservative) software limits, though most servos will work from 0.7ms to 2.3ms.

Answer (score 0):

Servo is probably broken, or fried.
Same thing happened to me, that too twice!
First time, I had fried the servo(overpowered it).
Second time, one of the gears had broken.(finally I managed to salvage one total servo by using gears from fried one in the one with broken gears)
First, try a different way to control the servo. If the servo fails to respond, then try opening up the servo.You might be able to salvage something.

Comment: P.S. If the servo is fried, there is not much you could do, but if one of the gears is broken, KEEP THE BOARD, as you can use it with another motor using Transistor H-Bridge.

Comment: If you are using a H-Bridge, you should probably use MOSFETs instead of the usual BJTs so that you can use larger Motors